# React Hooks: Check if JSON object exists in useState and add if it doesn't make one and add it to it?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a `<Day/>` component which is a child of a `<Calendar/>` component naturally;

`<Day/>` has a `dayInfo` prop. At this point I am trying to convert the `event.target.computedName` data I get from a click on the calendar and pass it to the day component like so: `<Day dayInfo={event.target.computedName}/>`

```
  event.target.computedName === 'April 9, 2020'
```

From there I'd like to convert it to an `JSON` object and then push it to state/array in the day component:

```
var [dayCollection, setDayInCollection] = useState([]);

So April 9, 2020 becomes:

dayCollection = [
  "April-9-2020" : {} // a JSON object awaits some data about the day!!!
]
```

So this is my Day component:

```
export default function Day({ dayInfo }) {
  var [dayCollection, setDayInCollection] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('dayInfo ', dayInfo);
    if (!dayInfo in dayCollection) {
      setDayInCollection(
        dayCollection.concat(
          JSON.parse(
            JSON.stringify(
              dayInfo
                .split(' ')
                .map((item) => {
                  if (item.indexOf(',')) return item.replace(/,/g, '');
                })
                .join('-')
            )
          )
        )
      );
    } else {
      console.log('do nothing');
    }
  }, [dayCollection]);

  console.log('dayCollection ', dayCollection);
  /* rest omited for brevity */
}
```

I believe I have the conversion of 'April 9, 2020' to "April-9-2020" as I've logged it, but the check of `dayCollection`/state continuously yields `[]`

So how do I check if that `JSON` object exists in the state of the Day component, and add it if it doesn't make a `JSON` object and concat it to the state?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First get modified dayInfo, then check if it's in dayCollection with `dayCollection.includes(modifiedDayInfo)` if it doesn't then add it: `setDayInCollection(dayInCollection.concat(modifiedDayInfo)` Not sure if you needed to put this in an effect, does exactly the same if you don't put it in an effect.

Comment: This is not how you check if an item exists in a collection in JavaScript; `if (!dayInfo in dayCollection) {}`, check [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @HMR Thank you, but that is having the effect of just returning `[0: "April-4-2020"]` I would like an array with `JSON objects` e.g. `["April-4-2020": {"weather":"sunny", "went_for_a_run": false}]`

Comment: In other words `"April-4-2020"` will become a JSON object property on the `dayInCollection` which is an array.